# Save notebook widget state in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Is there a possibility to save notebook widget state during export to html in vs code?
The widget appears well but it disappears when I export the notebook in html format. More precisely for my case, I display a map, I add data to it and the map is not displayed in the exported html file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it's not possible:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4404

> Thanks for the suggestion! We don't have plans to prioritize implementing this now, and if this issue receives upvotes from the community we will reconsider.